# On BLUR not firing

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, onblur

Recently changing from writing small vb apps to web apps. Haven't switched over to C# at this time.

Trying to get an ASP.net Form to add a couple text boxes and show the results in another text box.

This is on and ASP.NET 4.0 form using the `FormView` Control in insert mode.
The issue is that no matter if I click in the box, Tab into the box or out it doesn't ever seem to fire the JavaScript

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function SumCalc() 
{
    Window.alert("On Blur");
    var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("LeaveHoursTextBox").value);
    var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("LeaveHours2TextBox").value);
    var num3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("LeaveHours3TextBox").value);
    var TotalTime = num1 + num2 + num3

    document.getElementById("HoursTextBox").value = TotalTime;
}
</script>
```

Below is part of my html. Long page so I didn't post the whole of it..

```
<asp:TextBox ID="LeaveHoursTextBox" runat="server" 
Text='<%# Bind("LeaveHours") %>' 
onblur = "return sumCalc()"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind it via jQuery blur: http://api.jquery.com/blur/

You can do like this:

```
$("#LeaveHoursTextBox").blur(function(){
    Window.alert("On Blur");
    var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("LeaveHoursTextBox").value);
    var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("LeaveHours2TextBox").value);
    var num3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("LeaveHours3TextBox").value);
    var TotalTime = num1 + num2 + num3

    document.getElementById("HoursTextBox").value = TotalTime;
})
```

Comment: Ill need a little more help than that.  Where do I add that code piece to?

Comment: <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript">   </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#LeaveHoursTextBox").blur(function () {
        Window.alert("On Blur");
        var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("LeaveHoursTextBox").value);
        var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("LeaveHours2TextBox").value);
        var num3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("LeaveHours3TextBox").value);
        var TotalTime = num1 + num2 + num3

        document.getElementById("HoursTextBox").value = TotalTime;
    })
</script>

Comment: I can't get this to fire at all and also had to make a minor change.-----------$("#LeaveHoursTextBox").blur(function(){            ----------------------to------------- $(document.getElementById("LeaveHours2TextBox")).blur(function () {

Comment: You can't use the jquery in the second option... the `$("#LeaveHoursTextBox").` will already select just the element with the LeaveHoursTextBox id. You must add a call to this function... like `$(document).ready()`

Comment: try adding this: `<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#LeaveHoursTextBox").blur(function () { Window.alert("On Blur"); var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("LeaveHoursTextBox").value); var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("LeaveHours2TextBox").value); var num3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("LeaveHours3TextBox").value); var TotalTime = num1 + num2 + num3 document.getElementById("HoursTextBox").value = TotalTime; }) 
 });</script>`

Comment: Nope. Not running.. Not even making it to the Window.alert.

Comment: The following.... DOES NOT run.....

 </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function ()
         {
             $("#LeaveHoursTextBox").blur(function () {
            Window.alert("On Blur");
               
            })
        });
    </script>

It does not see the #LeaveHoursTextBox.  If this was a standard textbox on a regular page. This would most likely work. Please keep in mind this is a generated form

The following though.. Does..

 $("input[type=text][id*=LeaveHoursTextBox]").blur(function () { alert("hi") });

Comment: I have to give it to you. Short of setting initial values to '0' and changing a single line of code to your above stated solution I was finally able to get this to work.

Comment: $("input[type=text][id*=LeaveHoursTextBox]").blur(function () {

Answer (score 3):

Javascript is case sensitive. Change your call to `return SumCalc()`, also `Window.alert` won't work, use `window.alert` or just `alert` instead.

Further remove the spaces from `onblur = "return sumCalc()"`, valid html would be  `onblur="return sumCalc()"`.

Comment: Almost there. The alert fired. However the 3rd text box didn't get populated. I can't debug and step through so I at least know Im close.

Comment: Check the console for errors (in Chrome it's F12 to show developer tools).

Comment: Can I add the 'var' to the alert to see it's value as it passes?

Comment: well, you can `alert(num1);` or `console.log(num1);` after assigned, etc.. but you should be able to see the error in the console..

Comment: onblur is not a valid attribute of element textbox

Comment: Sorry. I add the click event that the text box seems to recocnize to get it to fire. Then removed and added the blur which the text box seems to not like.  Please correct me if im wrong but blur is used in replace of the lost focus event correct ?

Comment: Well, it's better to use jQuery, see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wUWYq/), I think it's exactly what you need

Comment: Im trying to.. See below... Can't get it to fire...Guys.. Im sorry but appreciate this..

Comment: Not firing.  IM Trying here..
OK.. Add the Class=XX to 
<asp:TextBox ID="LeaveHoursTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LeaveHours") %>' class="xx"/>

Added to all 3 textboxes

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.xx').blur(function () {

        var sum = 0;

        $.each($('.xx'), function (i, item) {
            sum += parseInt($(item).val()) || 0;
        });

        $('#leaveHours').val(sum);

    });
</script>

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that the rendered HTML element ID is different from your ASP.NET control ID? Unless you are on .NET 4.0+ and set `ClientIDMode="Static"`

Comment: Not enough reputation to chat.

Comment: id="MainContent_FormView1_LeaveHoursTextBox" class="xx"

Comment: fixed that but class is also not a valid attribute of element textbox

Comment: referencing the fiddle you sent me.

Comment: Do you have visual studio?  Create a page. Add a FormView with 2 text boxes bound to two fields.  IN INSERT MODE. When someone leaves focus of one of the two previous fields. Add that value to another textbox.  My god..This should be simple but it's proving sooooo painfull....Only due to lack of experience on my part of course.

Comment: `<asp:TextBox CssClass="xx" ../>` will render as `<input type="text" class="xx" .. />` in html

Comment: Lets try something easy just to see if we can get jquery to fire correctly.  I added added the alert back in to see if we are firing and its not reaching this.

Comment: CLOSER !!  This worked
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[type=text][id*=LeaveHoursTextBox]").blur(function () { alert("hi") });
    });
</script>

Comment: Michal. We were close in these methods. I just couldn't get them to work using asp forms in this method. I did get the JQuery example to work and had to offer the points to him as this did complete my solution.  Thank you all the same you were a great help and if I could I would issue yours a result as well for all your hard work.

Answer (score 3):

There are two issue,

**One**

Change `onblur = "return sumCalc()"` to `onblur = "return SumCalc()"/>`

There is a typo with the JS function you calling.

**Two**

Change `Window.alert("On Blur");` to `alert("On Blur");`